# Thunderbird deletes mails after recovering on OWA

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, imap, recovery, outlook-web-access

By mistake, I deleted all my mails in the inbox in thunderbird. Unfortunately, they didn't show up in deleted items nor in trash.
But I found all mails on Outlook Web App under recover deleted mails. So I recovered all mails. So far, so good.

Now I have all the mails back in OWA. But when I open Thunderbird again, the deleted mails do not show up. It seems that Thunderbird does not synchronize the folder.
But now when I close Thunderbird again, all mails are deleted again. The previously recovered mails disappear again from the inbox of OWA and I have to recover them all again.

I have already tried several things. I created a new folder and moved the recovered mails to that folder. All in the hope that this folder will then sync properly. Unfortunately no. The folder does not sync and as soon as Thunderbird is closed again, all mails are also deleted again from the new folder on OWA.

I even reset Thunderbird and linked Thunderbird to the account again. Unfortunately, the same thing happens again. The recovered mails are not displayed in Thunderbird and after closing the program, the mails are deleted again in OWA and I have to recover them again.

Any suggestions?

Best regards

---

Edit:

I have solved the problem for me, so to speak. I installed Evolution (alternative mail client) and did the same thing. (Recovered the mails via OWA.) Then Evolution deleted the mails once, but moved the mails to the deleted items. Thunderbird did not do that. After that, it was possible to recover the mails normally. So I think this unmarked the mails for deletion and the recover was successful. Obviously I don't trust thunderbird anymore for now and give Evolution a try.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I open Thunderbird again, the deleted mails do not show up. It seems that Thunderbird does not synchronize the folder. But now when I close Thunderbird again, all mails are deleted again. The previously recovered mails disappear again from the inbox of OWA and I have to recover them all again.

Sounds like the issue may need to be investigated further from the Thunderbird side. You can consider posting to the Thunderbird community as well to because there are more Thunderbird users over there and hopefully some of them have seen similar issues and can shed some lights on your situation.

Besides, if possible, you can try keeping Thunderbird closed, configuring the email account in another mail program like MS Outlook and see if the recovered can be seen. If everything is fine in Outlook, it's highly possible that it's an issue with Thunderbird, you may try clean uninstalling it from the machine and reinstall it to see if it can help.